# Prove the identity $\sin^4α-\cos^4α=2\sin^2α-1$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove the identity $\sin^4α-\cos^4α=2\sin^2α-1$

Well, I thought to start it this way:
$$(\sin^2α-\cos^2α)(\sin^2α+\cos^2α)=2\sin^2α-1=>\\(\sin α-\cos α)(\sin α+\cos α)(\sin^2α+\cos^2α)=2\sin^2α-1$$ I don't know how to continue...

Comment: Hint $cos^2a-sin^2a=cos2a$ and $sin^2a+cos^2a=1$ Gets you almost there

Comment: You were almost finished. You got to $(\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha)(\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha)$. This is $\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha$. Now replace $\cos^2\alpha$ by $1-\sin^2\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos^4a-\sin^4a=(\cos^2a−\sin^2a)(\cos^2a+\sin^2a)=(2\cos^2a-1)*1$ 
(becouse $\cos^2a−\sin^2a=\cos^2a-(1-\cos^2a)=2\cos^2a-1$)

Comment: Where can I prove that $cos^2a-sin^2a=2cos^2a$

Comment: @seda Looks like you made a little typo here

Comment: @seda , $cos^2a−sin^2a=cos^2a−(1−cos^2a)=2cos^2a-1$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$
\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2\alpha=1
$
substituting in the two sides you have the identity.